# Scheduled local notification fires every day instead of once per week

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am building an iOS app that makes use of local notifications to remind the user to complete a task, but only on the certain days (chosen by the user). The time at which the notification should fire is set by the date picker. My code is based on some code from another SO post.

Say the user would like to be reminded to complete said task on Sundays. The first thing I do is find out what the current date is, and get the correct components from it, then get the correct components from the date picker for the hour and minute.

```
//set up calendar and correct components
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear|NSCalendarUnitWeekday|NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:now]; //get the required calendar units
NSDateComponents *pickedComponents = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:picker.date];

NSDate *minuteHour = [calendar dateFromComponents:pickedComponents];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:minuteHour forKey:@"FireTime"];

NSString *reminder = @"Don't forget to check which customers are on vacation!";
```

Next, the data is saved, and the notification set up. This code is the same for every day of the week, with only the day name changed.

When the tempStatus is equal to "1", the user has chosen that day as a day to remind them.

```
//Save data
//sunday
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if ([sundayTempStatus isEqual:@"1"])
{
    //permanently save the status
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"1" forKey:@"Sunday"];

    //set up notifications
    //if it is past sunday, push next week
    if (components.weekday > 1)
    {
        components.weekOfYear++; //if already passed sunday, make it next sunday
    }

    components.hour = [pickedComponents hour];
    components.minute = [pickedComponents minute];

    NSDate *fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

    localNotification.fireDate = fireDate;
    localNotification.alertBody = reminder;
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
else
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"0" forKey:@"Sunday"];
}
```

Thanks in advance, and I will gladly provide more information and code if necessary.

Comment: Your date is wrong, instead of doing this `components.weekOfYear++;` you need to do `components.day=7*currentWeek` so your date is set to next sunday.

Comment: @iphonic I tried using `components.day = 7 * components.weekOfYear` since currentWeek was giving an error, but notifications totally stopped showing up. I then tried removing that entire if statement and added `components.day = 1` to set it to Sunday, but that didn't work either.